# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) in Angular-7 and Laravel-5.8

Tags: angular, laravel

I am developing a client portal application using Angular-7 as frontend and Laravel-5.8. I am using Larave Spatie for User Management. I have these three tables:

Laravel:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
`id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`client_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`client_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`client_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

From the tables above, I have two classes: User and Client.

1. Each user belong to a client, but not more that one.
2. client_id in client is also a Primary Key.

UsersController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Client;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use App\Notifications\SignupActivate;
use Avatar;
use Storage;
use App\Guardian;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if(!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Edit Users') && !Auth::user()->id==$id)
        return response()->json([ "message" => 'User do not have permission'], 401);
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:2',
        'client_id' => 'required'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);


    if($request->role){
        foreach($user->roles as $role)
            $user->removeRole($role);
        foreach($request->role as $role)
            $user->assignRole($role);
    }

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['data' => $user], 201);
}
}
```

ClientController.php

```
    public function clientAll(){
    return response()->json(Client::all());
}
```

api.php

```
Route::group([
'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
Route::get('users/profile', 'UsersController@profile');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' =>        ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
Route::post('users/pause', 'UsersController@pause');
});

Route::group([
'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
Route::get('client/clientall', 'ClientController@clientAll');
Route::resource('client', 'ClientController', ['only' =>    ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
});
```

During update of the user date, I want to have a dropdown select option populated with client_id/client_name. So that I can updated the user table with client_id.

[image: edit user]

Angular

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../../shared/services/api.service';
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {NgbPaginationConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { TokenService } from '../../../shared/services/token.service';
import { RolesCheckService } from 'src/app/shared/services/roles-check.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

users = null;     //Store Users Data
roles = null;     //Store all roles Data
clients = null;

public error = {
'role' : null,
'email' : null,
'client_id' : null,
'name' : null,
'password' : null
};
   //Form errors
 keyword = null;   //Current Search Keyword
 pagination = {    //Current Pagination data
'page' :  '1',
'max' : '10'
}
 role = null;
 User = 'User';

data = {          //User Update Data
 "id" : null,
 "name" : null,
 "client_id" : null,
 "role" : []
}

form = {         //New User add Data
  'name' : null,
  'email' : null,
  'client_id' : null,
  'password' : null,
  'password_confirmation' : null,
  'role' : []
 }

 headers = {     //Token for API Authorization
 'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }

  sortData = {        //Current Sort Data
   "col" : null,
   "order" : null
  }

 isSuperAdmin = false;

 constructor(private roleManage : RolesCheckService , private route : ActivatedRoute, private pg:   NgbPaginationConfig, private token : TokenService, private http : HttpClient, private router :    Router,private api : ApiService, private notify : SnotifyService) {
  pg.boundaryLinks = true;
  pg.rotate = true;
  }

 ngOnInit() {

 console.log('isSuperAdmin: ' + this.roleManage.isSuperAdmin);
 this.isSuperAdmin = this.roleManage.isSuperAdmin;
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
   if(params['role']){
    this.role = params['role'];
    this.User = this.role;

  } else {
    this.User = 'User';
    this.role = '';
  }
})
this.notify.clear();
this.notify.info("Loading...", {timeout: 0});

if(this.keyword) {
  this.api.get('users?search=' + this.keyword + '&page=' + this.pagination.page + '&sort=' + this.sortData.col + '&order=' + this.sortData.order + '&role=' + this.role, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => this.datahandler(data),
    error => { this.notify.clear(); console.log(error); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
  );
} else {
  this.api.get('users?page=' + this.pagination.page + '&sort=' + this.sortData.col + '&order=' + this.sortData.order + '&role=' + this.role, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => this.datahandler(data),
    error => { console.log(error); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
  );
}
this.api.get('role', this.headers).subscribe(
  data => { console.log(data); this.roles=data; },
  error => { console.log(error); this.notify.clear(); this.notify.error(error.error.message); }
);
this.api.get('client/clientall', this.headers).subscribe(
  data => this.clients = data,
  error => { this.notify.error(error.error.message) }
 );
}


 datahandler(data){
  console.log(data.data);
  this.notify.clear();
  this.users = data.data;
  this.pagination.max = data.total;
}

//sort handler
sort(col){
 console.log(col);
 if(this.sortData.order=="asc" && this.sortData.col==col){
  this.sortData.order = "desc"
 } else if(this.sortData.order=="desc" && this.sortData.col==col){
  this.sortData.order = null;
  col = null;
 } else {
  this.sortData.order = "asc"
 }
 this.sortData.col = col;
 this.ngOnInit();
}

//Paginate Handling
 paginateClick(page){
  console.log(page);
  this.pagination.page = page;
  this.ngOnInit();
 }

 //Serach Handling
 search(){
 this.ngOnInit();
 }

//Pause or Active User Handling
 pause(id){
 this.notify.clear();
 console.log(id);
 var body = {
  "id" : id
 }
 return this.api.post('users/pause', body, this.headers).subscribe(
  data => {this.notify.info("Success", {timeout: 2000}); this.ngOnInit(); },
  error => this.notify.error(error.message, {timeout: 0})
  );
 }

//User edit Handling
edit(id){
 this.notify.clear();
 this.data.name = null;
 this.data.role = [];
 this.api.get('users/'+id, this.headers).subscribe(
   data => this.editDataHandler(data),
   error => this.notify.error("User Not Found", {timeout: 0})
 );
 this.data.id = id;
 var modal = document.getElementById('editModal');
 modal.style.display = "block";
}

editDataHandler(data){
 console.log(data);
this.data.name = data.name;
for(var i=0; i<data.roles.length; i++)
  this.data.role.push(data.roles[i].name);
}

 checkbox(event){
   if(event.srcElement.checked){
   this.data.role.push(event.srcElement.name);
  } else {
   var index =this.data.role.indexOf(event.srcElement.name);
   this.data.role.splice(index, index+1);
  }
  console.log(this.data.role);
 }

editsubmit(){
  this.notify.clear();
  this.notify.info("Wait...", {timeout: 0});
  this.api.put('users/'+this.data.id, this.data, this.headers).subscribe(
   data => {
    this.notify.clear();
    this.notify.info("User Updated Successfully", {timeout: 2000});
    this.ngOnInit();
    this.closeEditModal();
  },
  error => { this.notify.clear(); this.error = error.error.errors; }
 );
}

closeEditModal(){
 this.error = {
  'role' : null,
  'email' : null,
  'client_id' : null,
  'name' : null,
  'password' : null
 };
 var modal = document.getElementById('editModal');
 modal.style.display = "none";
}

//User delete Handling
delete(id){
 this.notify.clear();
 this.notify.warning('Are you sure you want to detele this User?', 'Delete User', {
  timeout: 0,
  showProgressBar: false,
  closeOnClick: true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  buttons: [
    {text: 'Yes', action: () => {
      var headers = {
        'Authorization' : this.token.get()
      }
      return this.api.delete('users/'+id, headers).subscribe(
        data => {this.notify.info("Success", {timeout: 2000}); this.ngOnInit(); },
        error => this.notify.error(error.message, {timeout: 0})
      );
    }, bold: false},
    {text: 'No'}
  ]
 });
}

//New User add Handling
add(){
 this.notify.clear();

 this.form.name = null;
 this.form.email = null;
 this.form.password = null;
 this.form.password_confirmation = null;
 this.form.role = [];

 var modal = document.getElementById('addModal');
 modal.style.display = "block";
}


checkboxAdd(event){
  if(event.srcElement.checked){
    this.form.role.push(event.srcElement.name);
  } else {
    var index =this.form.role.indexOf(event.srcElement.name);
    this.form.role.splice(index, index+1);
  }
  console.log(this.form.role);
 }

  addModalSubmit(){
   this.notify.clear();
   this.notify.info("Wait...", {timeout: 0});
   this.api.post('users', this.form, this.headers).subscribe(
    data => {
     this.notify.clear();
     this.notify.info("User Added Successfully", {timeout: 2000});
    this.ngOnInit();
    this.closeAddModal();
   },
   error => { this.notify.clear(); this.error = error.error.errors; }
  );

 }

 closeAddModal(){
  this.error = {
   'role' : null,
   'email' : null,
   'client_id' : null,
   'name' : null,
   'password' : null
  };
 var modal = document.getElementById('addModal');
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

user.component.html

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="addModal" class="modal" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" (click)='closeAddModal()'>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.role">
            {{ error.role }}
          </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.email">
            {{ error.email }}
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.name">
              {{ error.name }}
            </div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!error.password">
              {{ error.password }}
            </div>
      <form #editUserForm=ngForm>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" name="name" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="form.name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required [(ngModel)]="form.email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Role</label>
                <div *ngFor="let role of roles">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ role.name }}" value="{{ role.name }}" (change)="checkboxAdd($event)"> {{ role.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" [(ngModel)]="form.password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Password Confirmation</label>
          <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="inputPasswordConfirm" [(ngModel)]="form.password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Re enter Password" required>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)='addModalSubmit()' [disabled]="!editUserForm.valid">Save changes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='closeAddModal()'>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I clicked on submit button (Save changes) I got this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

When I checked the developer's tool at the network, I found this error message:

[image: network error]

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP error 422 is returned by Laravel whenever you ask a `Controller` to validate a request and this validation fails. You use this validation in the `update` function of `UserController` with these lines:

```php
   $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:2',
        'client_id' => 'required'
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

So one of the rules must be failing validation. Luckily Laravel returns a `MessageBag` full of errors for you. If your `Accepts` HTTP error is set to json it will be a nice human readable response. Go ahead and open the developer tools of the browser you're using to test and look at the network response. You'll see something like this:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name must be at least 2 characters long."
        ]
    }
}
```

And this message bag of validation errors will point you to your issue.

Edit: Since we've narrowed it down to Angular failing to send the `client_id` there's 2 ways to solve your problem:

- Add a form field for the client_id, that is coupled to the `client_id` of the `data` object that you send in your update call:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Client</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="data.client_id">
        <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">
            {{ client.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

- Fake it as a proof of concept and figure it out from there ;)

```js
editsubmit(){

  this.data.client_id = 1;

  this.notify.clear();
  this.notify.info("Wait...", {timeout: 0});
  this.api.put('users/'+this.data.id, this.data, this.headers).subscribe(
   data => {
    this.notify.clear();
    this.notify.info("User Updated Successfully", {timeout: 2000});
    this.ngOnInit();
    this.closeEditModal();
  },
  error => { this.notify.clear(); this.error = error.error.errors; }
 );
}
```

Comment: I checked the developer's tool of the browser at the network as you advised and I got this:    {message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {client_id: ["The client id field is required."]}}
errors: {client_id: ["The client id field is required."]}
client_id: ["The client id field is required."]
message: "The given data was invalid."       How do I resolve it?

Comment: You should try to find out why the client_id is not being sent, or if it is not required for the client_id to be sent to update the user, then remove the `'client_id' => 'required'` validation rule.

Comment: @ayobamilaye I updated my answer to show you how to add the missing `client_id` to your update call. It might not be completely correct in the context of your specific code, but it solves the problem and answers the question. You can adapt to your wishes from here. If you could accept my answer that would be nice ;)